# Sign in with Slack Api, Android

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit2, slack

I am integrating the `Slack Api: Sign in with Slack`.  I have few things from `Slack Api`.

- Client ID : 'something'
- Client Secret: 'something'
- authorization Url: https://slack.com/oauth/authorize
- Token URL: https://slack.com/api/oauth.access
- scope: identify

I need the `code` parameter too.

In my `Activity` class, I am using `WebView` for this. To access `code` parameter, in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`  method I used:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("http://localhost:8000/")) {
            UrlQuerySanitizer urlQuerySanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer(url);
            String CLIENT_CODE = urlQuerySanitizer.getValue("code");
            Log.e(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+ CLIENT_CODE);
            loginPresenter.loginSuccess();
            return true;
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I make class called `HttpConstant` to keep url:

```
public class HttpsConstant {
    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_SLACK_URL = "https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar&client_id=something";
    public static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://slack.com/";
}
```

I make class called `StrngConstant` to keep this: `CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_CODE`.

```
public final class StringConstant {
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "something";
    public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "something" ;
    public static final String CLIENT_CODE = "something but still does not 
         able to pass the code parameter here from my activity class";
}
```

I am using `Retrofit` for login service:

```
public interface LoginService {
    @GET("api/oauth.access?client_id=" + StringConstant.CLIENT_ID + 
    "&client_secret=" + StringConstant.CLIENT_SECRET + 
    "&code="+ StringConstant.CLIENT_CODE)
    Call<LoginResponse> getLoginToken();
}
```

I have tried by using `SharedPreferences` in `shouldOverrideUrl` method but unable to use.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("ClientCode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Code", CLIENT_CODE);
editor.commit();
```

How can I pass `code` parameter in the login service ? How can I used this `SharedPreferences`, so I can access the `code` parameter? Or, is there any other way to get the `code` parameter and use this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have just set shared preference and not get in LoginService.

You have do like in LoginService

```
public interface LoginService {


SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("ClientCode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    @GET("api/oauth.access?client_id=" + StringConstant.CLIENT_ID + 
    "&client_secret=" + StringConstant.CLIENT_SECRET + 
    "&code="+ preferences.getString("Code",""))
    Call<LoginResponse> getLoginToken();
}
```

Similarity, you have to set and get for client_id and  client_secret.

Comment: Inside this LoginService class; getSharedPreferences can not be resolved, it say so too.

Comment: interface is for declaration not for detail implement.So use activity or fragment or static function in that pass Contex

Comment: That's why I used, StringConstant class.

Comment: but you have taken final varaible. its value can not be change. your way is not proper. you have to use function not interface where you should dynamically pass parameters